# How do I show a message box if the username is not in a database? C#

Tags: c#, database, foreach

Hi all I have a University project and I am coding a login screen, my text book is far too vague and I can't figure out how to show a message box if the user name is not inside the database. Here is my code:

```
public void login()
        {
            //try
            //{
                var tbl = from s in this.database1DataSet.employee
                          where s.Username == userNameBox.Text
                          select s;

                foreach (var s in tbl)
                {
                    if (s.Username == userNameBox.Text && s.Password == passwordBox.Text)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Access granted welcome " + s.fName);
                        this.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Access denied invalid login details");
                    }

                }
            //}
            /*catch (SyntaxErrorException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("User Does not exist");
            }*/`enter code here`
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: So, what's NOT working ?

Comment: @SLaks, that's typically true, but that may not necessarily be a requirement for his assignment

Comment: Generally you want to have the same message for a user "not existing" and a user "getting their credentials wrong". The reason for this is because someone could discover and infer another persons username by checking to see if "User does not exist" or "Invalid Login Credentials".

Comment: I agree we've only been coding in C# for 2 months so I don't think intensive security falls into the scope. I just need it to login or tell me that the user does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for existance of a user like:

```
if(!database1DataSet.employee.Any(r=> r.Username == userNameBox.Text))
{
    MesasgeBox.Show("User does not exist");
}
```

Also IMO, its better if you check the user name and password together, and show a message like `"Invalid Username/password"` instead of multiple messages.

```
var user = database1DataSet
                  .employee
                  .FirstOrDefault(r=> r.Username == userNameBox.Text &&
                                 r.Password == passwordBox.Text)

if(user != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Access granted welcome " + user.fName);
    this.Close();

}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password");
}
```

Also see: [Why encrypt user passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213068/why-encrypt-user-passwords)

Answer (score 4):

If your `where` clause doesn't match any users, there won't be any rows in the results.
Therefore, your loop will never execute.

Instead, you can call `FirstOrDefault()` to get the first result row, or `null` if there aren't any.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
var user = (from s in this.database1DataSet.employee
           where s.Username == userNameBox.Text &&
           s.Password == passwordBox.Text
           select s).FirstOrDefault();

if(user != null{
     MessageBox.Show("Access granted welcome " + s.fName);
     this.Close();
 }
 else{
    MessageBox.Show("Access denied invalid login details");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void login()
    {
            var tbl = from s in this.database1DataSet.employee
                      where s.Username == userNameBox.Text
                      select s;

            if(tbl.Count() == 0)
            {
              MessageBox.Show("User Does not exist");
              return; // or this.Close(); if it's what you want
            }

            foreach (var s in tbl)
            {
                if (s.Username == userNameBox.Text && s.Password == passwordBox.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Access granted welcome " + s.fName);
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Access denied invalid login details");
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, assuming your usernames are unique, you will only ever have 0 or 1 values in tbl.  That's fine, but be aware of it.  Second, you're wanting to have different functionality of the size of tbl is 0, or 1.  This is easily done with an if statement.  If there is an entry, check credentials.  Otherwise, show an error message for invalid username.  Since this is a course project, I won't actually write sample code for you, but that should be enough to get it working.  Good luck!