# Username and Password validate doesn't work in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables, session-cookies

I wrote a function in PHP to check username and password from MySQL database and store as session after successful validation. But whatever value I enter to the input box it approves it and made a successful login. My Login code doesn't work

here it is

```
function queryByUserAndPass($tableName, $username, $password){
    $queryStatement = "SELECT * FROM ".$tableName." WHERE username='".$username."' 
                      AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
    return $queryStatement;
}

function checkLogIn() {

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $queryState = queryByUserAndPass("nepal_users", $username, $password);
        if( $resultQuery = mysql_query($queryState) ){
            $found_user= mysql_fetch_array($resultQuery);
            $_SESSION['id']=$found_user['id'];
            $_SESSION['username']=$found_user['username'];
            $message="succesful log in ".$_SESSION['username'];
            header("location:home.php");
            exit;
        }else {
            $message="error in log in";
        }    

    }

}
```

Please tell me what is wrong in this code and why it is not working.

Comment: function queryByUserAndPass($tableName, $username, $password){
  $queryStatement = "SELECT * FROM ".$tableName." WHERE username='".$username."' 
       AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
  return $queryStatement;
 }

Comment: Dont you have some encryption on the users password ?? If you have , You have to apply the same method

Comment: have you initialized your session with session_start();

Comment: Remember to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on your username and password input before putting them in the database - otherwise anyone could put `' or 1='1` as the password and gain access to the username of their choice.

Comment: FYI: [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/332367/29995), [password encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3107832/29995)

Comment: Pls sanitise your data flow/prepared statements, mysql_escape_string, mysql_real_escape_string, addslashes .../ and use always ecryption hash algorithms to protect your passwords/plus salts/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont check if username and password are correct!

```
    if( $resultQuery = mysql_query($queryState) ){
        $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($resultQuery);
        if ($username === $found_user['username'] &&
          $password === $found_user['password']) {
            $_SESSION['id']=$found_user['id'];
            $_SESSION['username']=$found_user['username'];
            $message="succesful log in ".$_SESSION['username'];
            header("Location: home.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "wrong username or password";
        }
    }else {
        $message="error from database: " . mysql_errno($resultQuery);
    }
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

The code above just illustrates where the logic problem in your code is. There are two other serious issues in it:

1. Its vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Using prepared statements is common practise. If prepared statemements are not availabe to you, use something like `$SAFE_USER_DATA = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);` and use this instead of directly reading `$_POST`data. That way you ensure no malicious user can modify your SQL statements to gain access to your system.
2. You should never store passwords as plain text - storing a *salted* SHA1 password hash is encouraged. do NOT simply use `md5($password)`. Attackers can easily decrypt those with the help of [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)

Comment: It is safe to assume that the username and password are put into the query by the `queryByUserAndPass` function.

Comment: @Kolink you are right, the OP posted the function in a comment after i posted my answer. However, the quick fix illustrated here should work, too. despite the serious issues regarding SQL injection and missing password hashes, though..

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_query` always returns a resource on success, or false if there is an error in your code.

What you want to do is:

```
$resultQuery = mysql_query($queryState);
if( $found_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultQuery)) {
    // do login stuff
    // note I used "fetch_assoc" above, because you don't use numeric indices here.
}
else $message = "Error";
```

Comment: Reciprocal +1 for the real fix