# Theory Question regarding Cryptography in NodeJS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, cryptojs, password-encryption

I have an application built in NodeJS that connects to a mongo database. I would like for the password to be encrypted when a user signs up (saved into the database) and then decrypted and verified when the user logs in at a later time. Also, as another caveat, the user's credentials, e.g. the username & password, will be used at a later point in time to connect to a 3rd party API, so I have to be able to retrieve the unencrypted password later as well. I have researched the crypto library for encryption and decryption used by Node apps. The issue I am running into is when the app server starts, of course we generate a random key and iv. Let's say you sign a user up and you encrypt that user's password with that particular key and iv. As long as the same key and iv are being used, I have no problems, but let's say you had to restart your application. This would generate a new key and iv, and therefore cause issues because you encrypted your data the first time with the previous key and iv. If generating new keys and iv's randomly are best practice, how am I to encrypt data and then decrypt it a later time? I may be misunderstanding the approach of how to implement, so I am just looking for best practices.

Using the crypto library and basic code implementation from sources. I was able to use the same key every time, but the iv that is generated changes on app startup.

```
/* eslint-disable no-trailing-spaces */
const crypto = require('crypto');

const encryptionService = {
  encrypt: (data) => encrypt(data),
  decrypt: (data) => decrypt(data),
};

module.exports = encryptionService;

// Encryption details
const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc'; // Using AES encryption
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const secretKey = 'somesecretkey';

const key = crypto
  .createHash('sha256')
  .update(String(secretKey))
  .digest('base64')
  .substr(0, 32);

const encrypt = (data) => {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(key), iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(data);
  encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
  const encryptedPassword = encrypted.toString('hex');
  console.log('encrypted pw = ', encryptedPassword);
  return encryptedPassword;
};

const decrypt = (data) => {
  const encryptedText = Buffer.from(data, 'hex');
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
  decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
  console.log('decrypted pw = ', decrypted.toString());
  return decrypted.toString();
};
```

Comment: This is confusing. When does the user need to enter their password? And if they're already entering their password every time they use the app then why do you need to encrypt it for storage?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk the user will enter their password when they signup, also again when they login (which can be anytime in the future). To follow HIPPA standards, passwords need to be encrypted for obvious reasons. Hope that helps!

Comment: HIPPA does not require encrypted passwords, it requires best practices. Best practices for passwords are to store them hashed using a hash algorithm designed specifically for passwords like argon2, scrypt, bcrypt, or the older pbkdf2.

Comment: What you really need to do is hire an actual security expert, and not depend on the freely given opinions of random people on the internet...

Comment: There are entire certifications for _**industry-standard**_ security professionals to implement best-practice in corporations. It's called [`CompTIA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompTIA) ([Computing Technology Industry Association](https://www.comptia.org/)), and it's accredited by [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute) ([American National Standards Institute](https://www.ansi.org/)). They have a [`Security+`](https://www.comptia.org/certifications/server) certification. See: [Mike Meyers Total Semianrs](https://www.totalsem.com/security-certification/).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Entirely agree! Just wanted a sanity check.

Comment: @Nyctfall definitely not getting looking to get a certification to solve this. But thank you!

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I can't use hashing, e.g. bcrypt, because I need to be able to read the user's password back at some point in the future to make a call to a 3rd party API and validate there as well. Bcrypt's hashing is a one-way operation and therefore I can't read the password back.

Answer (score 1):

There's already been much work done in this space by large organizations focused on security, so there are plenty of tools to accomplish authentication.

Only encrypting passwords is not sufficient, as it's possible to use decryption to get the password. Encryption should ***ALWAYS*** be done in *transport* ([HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) with [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)), with encrypted ***connections*** to the server.
Encrypted database storage would also be beneficial for security.

***Storage*** of passwords is done by [hashing](https://www.okta.com/blog/2019/03/what-are-salted-passwords-and-password-hashing/), ensuring they can't be reversed back into a password. (the ***ability*** get the original password is the **most** severe vulnerability when dealing with passwords, whether [in use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_in_use), [in transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_in_transit), or [at rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_at_rest)).

> Instead the newly submitted password's ***hash*** is compared with the original password's **hash**.

---

#### Store secrets using [`.env`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#usage):

> Create a `.env` file in the root of your project:
>
> ```
>  SECRET_KEY="YOUR_SECRET_KEY_GOES_HERE"
> ```
>
> As early as possible in your application, `import` and configure `dotenv`:
>
> ```
>  require('dotenv').config()
>  console.log(process.env) // remove this after you've confirmed it is working
> ```
>
> `process.env` now has the keys/value pairs you defined in your `.env` file.

Make sure you don't include the contents of `.env` in **any** git repo or anywhere visible to someone without special security authorization.

---

#### Hash passwords using [BCrypt](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js):

> ```
> const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
> const saltRounds = 10
> const plaintextPassword = "some_password"
> bcrypt.hash(plaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
>   // store  hash  in DB ...
> })
> ```
>
> To check a password:
>
> ```
> // load password hash from DB ...
> bcrypt.compare(plaintextPassword, hash, function(err, result) {
>   // result === true
> })
> bcrypt.compare("someOtherPlaintextPassword", hash, function(err, result) {
>   // result === false
> })
> ```
>
> The characters that comprise the resultant hash are
>
> ```
> ./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789$.
> ```
>
> Resultant hashes will be 60 characters long and they will include the salt (IV) among other parameters, as follows:
>
> ```
>  $[algorithm]$[cost]$[salt][hash]
> ```
>
> - 2 chars hash algorithm identifier prefix. "$2a$" or "$2b$" indicates BCrypt
> - Cost-factor (n). Represents the exponent used to determine how many iterations 2^n
> - 16-byte (128-bit) salt, base64 encoded to 22 characters
> - 24-byte (192-bit) hash, base64 encoded to 31 characters
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> $2b$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veuK0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
>  |  |  |                     |
>  |  |  |                     hash-value = K0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
>  |  |  |
>  |  |  salt = nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veu
>  |  |
>  |  cost-factor => 10 = 2^10 rounds
>  |
>  hash-algorithm identifier => 2b = BCrypt
> ```

---

#### Use 3rd-Party API tokens, like OAuth, OpenID, and JWT:

###### [JWT](https://jwt.io/):

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is a standard ([RFC 7519](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519)) that defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object. This information can be verified and trusted because it is digitally signed. JWTs can be signed using a secret (with the HMAC algorithm) or a public/private key pair using RSA or ECDSA.
>
> Although JWTs can be encrypted to also provide secrecy between parties, the focus is on signed tokens. Signed tokens can verify the integrity of the claims contained within it, while encrypted tokens hide those claims from other parties. When tokens are signed using public/private key pairs, the signature also certifies that only the party holding the private key is the one that signed it.
>
> - Authorization: This is the most common scenario for using JWT. Once the user is logged in, each subsequent request will include the JWT, allowing the user to access routes, services, and resources that are permitted with that token. Single Sign On is a feature that widely uses JWT, because of its small overhead and its ability to be easily used across different domains.

```
jwt.sign({ foo: "bar" }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { algorithm: 'RS256' }, function(err, token){
  console.log(token)
})
```

###### [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth):

> OAuth (Open Authorization) is a protocol for authorization for an application to use user information. It allows third party applications to access user data from an application like Google, without giving the third party app (the Express app) the user password.
> You might have seen a “login with Google” login page of a website. This is done with the OAuth.

###### [OpenID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)

> OpenID [Connect](https://www.okta.com/openid-connect/) is the third generation of [OpenID technology](https://openid.net/connect/faq/). It is an authentication layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 authorization framework.
>
> It allows Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and REST-like manner.
>
> OpenID Connect performs many of the same tasks as OpenID 2.0, but does so in a way that is API-friendly, and usable by native and mobile applications. OpenID Connect defines optional mechanisms for robust signing and encryption. Whereas integration of OAuth 1.0a and OpenID 2.0 required an extension, in OpenID Connect, OAuth 2.0 capabilities are integrated with the protocol itself.

- The [Passport.js](https://www.passportjs.org), [Passport OpenID](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-openid/), and [Passport OAuth2](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-oauth2/) packages can be used for integrating with OAuth and OpenID.

---

Sources:

[Why aren't original passwords stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107810/why-arent-original-passwords-stored)

[What are salted passwords and password hashing](https://www.okta.com/blog/2019/03/what-are-salted-passwords-and-password-hashing/)

[Why is password hashing considered so important](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41447/why-is-password-hashing-considered-so-important)

[Why should I hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36833/why-should-i-hash-passwords)

[Data At Rest (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_at_rest)

[Data in use (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_in_use)

[Data in transit (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_in_transit)

[`node-jsonwebtoken`](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)

[OpenID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)

[OpenID Connect](https://www.okta.com/openid-connect/)

[OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

[Passport.js](https://www.passportjs.org)

[JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/)

[`passport-oauth2`](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-oauth2/)

[`passport-openid`](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-openid/)

[RFC 7519](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519)

[Node.js `bcrypt`](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js)

[node `dotenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#usage)

[OpenID Foundation](https://openid.net/connect/faq/)

[HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)

[TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Nyctfall but I can't use bcrypt's hashing because that is a one way action, meaning once I hash the password I can't read it back at a later time. I realize that I'm in a unique position because the app I'm working on needs to read back the password for later use. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @TrapperDavis! It's possible to simply store each password's specific salt in the same MongoDB document as the user and password. That way, the corresponding salt is retrieved for each password. But again, it's good practice to _store_ passwords **hashed _and_ encrypted**, so the database cannot leak encrypted user passwords (like [LastPass](https://www.tomsguide.com/news/lastpass-hack-was-even-worse-than-originally-reported-should-you-delete-your-account) did recently), or be misused and decrypted by bad actors. API tokens were created to use 3rd-parties without exposing user passwords.